# What are some of the GitHub alternatives that you consider for Bitcoin Core and other Bitcoin related projects?

Tags: source-code

Time for Bitcoin Core and other bitcoin related projects to look for GitHub alternatives?

Some of the issues:

https://techcrunch.com/2019/07/29/github-ban-sanctioned-countries/

https://twitter.com/lrvick/status/1320246266270519297

https://twitter.com/jonatack/status/1315623229747322880

Comment: There is a GitHub issue here that is probably better suited for this discussion. I can't imagine anything other than GitLab will be seriously considered. We don't want to experiment with immature platforms or make a habit of jumping around. I could be wrong though. https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/20227

Answer (score 4):

A list of some GitHub alternatives is [here](https://itsfoss.com/github-alternatives/).

- GitLab
- BitBucket
- SourceForge
- Launchpad
- Google Cloud Source Repositories
- AWS CodeCommit
- Phabricator
- Gogs (Self-Hosted)
- Gitea (Self-Hosted)
- Apache Allura (Self-Hosted)

This [GitHub Repo Full Downloader](https://github.com/achow101/github-dl) written by Andrew Chow may also be of interest.

Discussion on whether to move from GitHub and where to move to should be had on IRC and GitHub rather than here. StackExchange isn't set up for discussions and conversations and it will get very noisy if everyone expresses a view here.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the alternatives. IRC- I don't have good experience. Asked two questions: Dandelion and Android IRC client. Got no response from anyone. Most of the time it's dead and looks like only few people talk between themselves. I was avoiding GitHub because discussing controversial things on GitHub that involve GitHub may lead to censorship of issue or me getting banned.

Comment: Lots of channels that are very active. Maybe you were just unfortunate at the times you posted. Anyone will generally get a response on #bitcoin-core-pr-reviews from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there have been lot of issues recently related to GitHub.

Alternatives: [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) and [radicle](https://radicle.xyz/)